# Site to Site VPN using GNS3

Tags: vpn, gns3, l2vpn

I'm sorry if this a really vague question - but I am trying to get my head around a problem and a possible solution.  I'm not really a network guy (not to the depths of you guys) - I'm a PLC programmer.
Currently I use a radmin VPN on a remote and local laptops to allow me to remote onto PLC's/ HMI's.  For the most part this works great - but any layer 2 packets are dropped, which does restrict me a little.  Hence I am trying to come up with ways to overcome this.  Whilst researching ways to overcome this I came across GNS3...

Whilst I have close to zero experience programming cisco switches (I once got a vpn going on 2 physical devices above a decade ago) - my thoughts were could I possibly run GNS3 on a local and remote laptop to provide a layer 2 vpn?

The remote laptops do change and if an end customer requires support - I may have to setup their laptop using anydesk or similar - and this usually takes me 1/2 hour, so whatever solution I go with would need to be configurable (once I have all the elements in place etc.) in around the same time.

I would appreciate any input - pointers to guides etc. etc.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: GNS3 is a network simulator used for education and training.  It's NOT useable for any sort of production use.

Comment: I appreciate that.  But the scenario in this case would be that it isnt really critical - I have drop outs from radmin etc. and I typically only need to connect to 3 devices.  I could even limit its use further for when I need to discover devices (the part that I need layer 2 capabilities for).

Comment: You're really trying to use a bicycle when you need an airplane.  GNS3 is a training tool that simulates routers in software. So you would also need router licenses.   It has VERY limited hardware capabilities.  I don't know if you can even create a a VPN to an external device.

Answer (score 1):

L2 over WAN/VPN isn't very reliable and potentially creates all sorts of security and liability issues that may get hard to manage when used with networks from other organizations/clients. As commented, GNS3 is completely unsuitable for production, generally.

We cannot recommend any specific products here. However, I'd recommend considering a dedicated maintenance machine (hardware or VM) in the target network. Then you can remote control that machine (using a remote tool or VPN solution) and have full L2 access from there.